# Is it possible to make a struct return a value directly?

Tags: c++, struct, enums

I wish to be able to return a value directly from a struct when it's called instead of accessing what I want through its member functions. Is this possible?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum FACE { NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST };

struct Direction {
    FACE face;
};

int main(){
    Direction dir;
    dir.face = EAST;

    cout << dir;  // I want this to print EAST instead of having to do dir.face
}
```

Comment: You can provide an `ostream& operator<<(ostream& , FACE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add operator of conversion `FACE`:

```
struct Direction {
    // .. Previous code

    operator FACE () const { return face; }
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/2y5v7P)

Comment: This is what I was after. Sorry I wrote the example quickly and chose a silly cout scenario causing some people to think I was trying to get a string return type when really I was just after this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the `<<` operator to do that.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Direction const& dir)
{
    return os << dir.face;
}
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/d5NQNy)

Or if you want the string "EAST" instead of the `int` value in the enum

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Direction const& dir)
{
    std::string face = "";
    switch(dir.face)
    {
    case(NORTH):
        os << "NORTH";
        break;
    case(SOUTH):
        os << "SOUTH";
        break;
    case(EAST):
        os << "EAST";
        break;
    case(WEST):
        os << "WEST";
        break;
    }
    return os << face;
}
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/IO1GEj)